# Claiming disk space after removing table field

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, shrink

I am running sql 2008 r2 and the db was working fine and fast for last 3 years untill about 3 months ago we added ntext field on very active and used table. 
Now we are starting to get out of server space because of the huge expanding size of this table.

I read that shrinking ,we do not want to loose the indexing of db because it was working fast for years and we do not want to get fragmentation expending.

**We decided to delete that field and all its values:**
Is there a way to delete the ntext field and all its values and release space without removing indexing ,without shrinking, without loosing db performance?

I am attaching the db size query output to show you size expanding of last 5 months.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> We decided to delete that field and all its values: Is there a way to delete the ntext field and all its values and release space without removing indexing ,without shrinking, without loosing db performance?

I would recommend to use *[(from BOL : )](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174418.aspx)*

```
DBCC CLEANTABLE
(
    { database_name | database_id | 0 }
    , { table_name | table_id | view_name | view_id }
    [ , batch_size ]
)
[ WITH NO_INFOMSGS ]
```

> DBCC CLEANTABLE reclaims space after a variable-length column is dropped. A variable-length column can be one of the following data types: varchar, nvarchar, varchar(max), nvarchar(max), varbinary, varbinary(max), text, ntext, image, sql_variant, and xml. The command does not reclaim space after a fixed-length column is dropped.

!! **CAUTION** !! *(**use a careful batch size** - its advisable to use this parameter if your table is massive)*:

> DBCC CLEANTABLE runs as one or more transactions. If a batch size is **not** specified, the command processes the whole table in one transaction and **the table is exclusively locked during the operation**. For some large tables, the length of the single transaction and the log space required may be too much. If a batch size is specified, the command runs in a series of transactions, each including the specified number of rows. DBCC CLEANTABLE cannot be run as a transaction inside another transaction.
>
> **This operation is fully logged.**

A simple repro will prove that `DBCC CLEANTABLE` is better than SHRINKING (and no worry of fragmentation :-)

```
-- clean up
drop table dbo.Test

-- create test table with ntext column that we will drop later
create table dbo.Test (
    col1 int
    ,col2 char(25)
    ,col3 ntext
    );

-- insert  1000 rows of test data
declare @cnt int;

set @cnt = 0;

while @cnt < 1000
begin
    select @cnt = @cnt + 1;

    insert dbo.Test (
        col1
        ,col2
        ,col3
        )
    values (
        @cnt
        ,'This is a test row # ' + CAST(@cnt as varchar(10)) + 'A'
        ,REPLICATE('KIN', ROUND(RAND() * @cnt, 0))
        );
end
```

[image]

[image]

```
--drop the ntext column
ALTER TABLE dbo.Test DROP COLUMN col3 ;
```

[image]

[image]

```
--reclaim the space from the table
-- Note that my table is only having 1000 records, so I have not used a batch size
-- YMMV .. so find a maintenance window and you an appropriate batch size 
-- TEST TEST and TEST before implementing in PROD.. so you know the outcome !!
DBCC CLEANTABLE('tempdb', 'dbo.Test') ;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: After you've executed the DBCC CLEANTABLE command, you need to REBUILD your clustered index in case the table has one, in order to get back the space.

ALTER INDEX IndexName ON YourTable REBUILD;

Answer (score 6):

For most parts I'm referencing Paul Randall's [Inside the storage engine](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/category/inside-the-storage-engine/) blog series.

The only way to reclaim unused space from database files in SQLServer is using the DBCC SHRINK command which reallocates data within the database files freeing pages and after removing them from the Global Allcation map removes them from the database file. This operation is slow, creates fragmentation within the database and is even slower when dealing with LOB pages as those are stored as linked lists within the database files.

Since you are dropping the NTEXT column you will have to wait for the ghost cleanup process to drop the data before shrinking.

Now having lots of free space in the database files will actually do you no harm, if you have the disk space, backup compression will take care of the free space within the files.

If you absolutely want to make the files smaller you can create a new filegroup with the database and make it the default and then move the tables into the new filegroup but this can take time and cause downtime. I have used the technique explained [here by Bob Pusateri](http://www.bobpusateri.com/archive/2013/03/moving-a-database-to-new-storage-with-no-downtime/) with good results.

Comment: will the ghost cleanup process will reduce the space or shrink will also required?

Comment: you will always have to shrink, The cleanup process only empties the allocated pages but does not remove them from the database files

Comment: @Spörri `Since you are dropping the NTEXT column you will have to wait for the ghost cleanup process to drop the data before shrinking.` Please see [my answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/117450/8783). You can use `DBCC CLEANTABLE` to release the space.

Answer (score 4):

Do you want to shrink the database files because you need that space for other databases/non DB files or because you are having problems with this database running out of space?

If it's the second then you may not have as big a problem as you think. If I'm correct your problem is when the database needs to grow to gain additional space for new data.  Once you remove the column all of the space taken up by that column will be freed for new rows to be added to tables in the database.  This means that it will be longer before your database needs to grow.  In the mean time I would get some additional space for your data drive.  Most databases do grow over time and it's nice to have a healthy margin of free space on the drive.

Comment: we have only 10gb left on disk space and it will also run out in few days. we have removed all what we could remove from server and used cleanups and stoped windows updates and remvoed them all and cleaned the winsxs , we now must reduce the size of the db file

Comment: Again, remember that once you have deleted the extra column your DB growth will stop for a time while you fill up the new space you freed up.  If your DB is still growing after this point then you will absolutely need additional disk space for your database.  Possibly add a new drive to your server.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a mirror table without the offending column, copy all data into this table, drop the original and then rename the mirror table.

Comment: in that case all indexes will also needed to prepared

Comment: yes the any indexes affecting the table will need to be dropped & recreated also.... also applies to other objects referencing the table eg: triggers